# Append object to child object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following object:

```
var dpsets = {
    "routes": [
        {
            "name": "first",
            "values": [
                "info",
                "more info",
                "text"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "second",
            "values": [
                "text again",
                "with info"

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I also have the following object:

```
var currentSet = {
    "name": "New Route",
    "values": [
        "Latest one",
        "Latest two"
    ]
}
```

I am trying to append `currentSet` to the `routes` element of `dpsets`.

I have tried both `dpsets.routes.push(currentSet)` and jQuery's `$.extend(dplocations.routes, currentRoute)` but neither seemed to do what I require.

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: "dpsets.routes.push(currentSet);" works for me.

Comment: check this it works.. - http://jsfiddle.net/zPzY3/

Comment: What exactly doesn't work for you with `dpsets.routes.push(currentSet)`?

Comment: I just tried dpsets.routes.push(currentSet) again and it worked this time. Thanks for all suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally this didn't work:

`dpsets.routes.push(currentSet)`

However, after trying it again, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
dpsets.routes.push((currentSet));

alert(JSON.stringify(dpsets));
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbN9P/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var dpsets = {
"routes": [
    {
        "name": "first",
        "values": [
            "info",
            "more info",
            "text"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "second",
        "values": [
            "text again",
            "with info"

        ]
    }
]
};
var currentSet = {
    "name": "New Route",
    "values": [
        "Latest one",
        "Latest two"
    ]
};

dpsets.routes.push(currentSet);
console.log(dpsets);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jLNqt/)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to use the method concat()?

dpsets.concat(currentSet)